# C# - Portable Class Library "XmlElement does not exist in the namespace System.XML"

Tags: c#, xml, service, reference

I'm creating a PCL (Portable Class Library) that uses a service reference that I use to consume some services, but when I try to compile I get this errors:

> "XmlElement does not exist in the namespace System.XML" in the reference.cs file
>
> "schema could not be found" in the reference.cs file

I'm getting completely crazy about this.
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

Referenced Windows.Data.Xml.Dom as suggested, and modified the reference.cs (just to give it a try) but im still getting the schema error and I have no idea from which namespace it is

**SOLVED:**
I was using an object that could not be serialized (dataset) that was the blame for the bad class schema

Thanks for your help anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PCL probably targets versions of the .NET framework where the `XmlElement` class does not exist.

Looking at the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx), it doesn't seem to mention Silverlight, XNA, Windows Phone, or WinRT... so if you're targeting any of these - `System.XML.XmlElement` simply isn't available.

You'll have to look for an equivalent type that *is* available on all the platforms you're targeting, or use a 3rd party library. For example, there is a [`Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.data.xml.dom.xmlelement) available on Windows 8 / Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I suspected the problem was that but I just tried it and the same error appears. The problem is that the error occurs in the reference.cs that is auto-generated

Comment: @dcastro how can I achieve this in Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 1):

XMLElement found in `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom namespace`

Add the reference

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem maintains because the error occurs in the auto-generated file reference.cs

Comment: Without having your code we can only guess.. Please share your code

Comment: Selected his answer as correct because of the explanation but thanks anyway

Comment: In Xamarin, from where can i get add this reference?